# git repo of the GAE SDK

Tags: google-app-engine

Do you know that is there any repo(git, or something else) of the GAE python SDK? it's annoying to always download zip file(~23MB) when new version is released :P

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An SVN repository us available here:
http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/checkout